# Wordpress plugin is not creating table when activating

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working to develop a plugin that needs to create a table in database here is my code please help
the code is not showing any errors and not creating the table

```
public function create_phone_order_db() {

    global $wpdb;


$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'phone_orders';
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $table_name . " ( 
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        billing_country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
        billing_first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        billing_last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        billing_company VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        billing_address_1 VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 
        billing_address_2 VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 
        billing_city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        billing_state VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
        billing_postcode VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
        billing_email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
        billing_phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
        ship_to_different_address VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
        shipping_country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        shipping_first_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
        shipping_last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
        shipping_company VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        shipping_address_1 VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 
        shipping_address_2 VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL, 
        shipping_city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        shipping_state VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
        shipping_postcode VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
        admin_email_switched VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
        admin_switched_id INT NOT NULL, 
        admin_user_name_switched VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
        admin_role_switched VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
        order_comments VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        shipping_method VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        payment_method VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        _wpnonce VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        _wp_http_referer VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) " . $charset_collate . ";";
    dbDelta($sql);
}
```

register_activation_hook( **FILE**, array($this, 'create_phone_order_db'));

Comment: Are you sure that table doesn't exists in your database? Note that you have `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: yup it does not exist .. i think the table i am creating is too big ...

Comment: Try to `echo $sql;` and execute your raw SQL from phpMyAdmin, or paste the query here if you don't have phpMyAdmin installed.

Comment: I have done it  before the query is fine .... i am going to remove most of the fields from my sql query and see if it works or not??

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with number of fields in your query, don't worry about it. Instead, you could try to debug (e.g. using `die`) to see if `create_phone_order_db` is being executed when you activate your plugin.

Comment: Hey it worked fine ..!! thank u so much for your help .. there were so many fields so i have just keep 4 of them and now the table is created .. now i need to add some more columns by a different query

Comment: Generally this happens when there is error in sql query, you can write `die($sql);` where you have `dbDelta($sql);` to check your sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to WordPress [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook#Examples) you should do

```
   class MyPlugin {
       static function install() {
          global $wpdb;
          $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';

$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    name tinytext NOT NULL,
    text text NOT NULL,
    url varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
) $charset_collate;";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
       }
   }

   register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array( 'MyPlugin', 'install' ) );
```

You can read more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) on creating a table on plugin activation.